# Refrigerator air damper stuck due to ice

Tags: refrigerator

I have a side by side two door refrigerator. Recently there was a problem where the normal refrigerator section was getting high temp alerts. Freezer section was working fine. I called a repair guy and he replaced air damper (installed between the two sides of refrigerator). Things seems ok for few days but the same problem came back. I checked the new damper closely and noticed that there is icing around air damper door mechanism and it was not opening due to icing, thus causing high temp on other side.

What could be causing this problem of icing ?  Repair company has no appointment for next two weeks, so i'm wondering if i can do something to mitigate the icing situation.

Comment: Do you have lots of items producing moisture in the fridge side ie stuff in open containers? Try using sealed containers..

Comment: Is ice building up in the freezer? There could be a problem with your defrost cycle.

Comment: No ice in freezer. Fridge section has normal load, some veggies, milk eggs. Food in closed containers.

Comment: @prashant, we’re you able to find the root cause of the problem? If you did posting that as an answer will close out the question and may help others. Plus you may get additional up votes for the answer.